# Оптимизация запроса с JOIN по текстовому полю

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli, оптимизация

Есть 2 таблицы - Clients1 и Clients2.

```
clients1
-----------
id (int, 11)
telephone (varchar, 32)
----------

clients2
----------
id (int, 11)
phone (varchar, 32)
----------
```

В каждой по 300 000 записей. Нужно выбрать все из таблицы clients1 и все `id` из clients2 где совпадают номера телефонов в обоих таблицах, то есть `clients1.telephone = clients2.phone`.
Пробовал делать с помощью LEFT JOIN и подзапроса, но отрабатывает очень долго, так как поля текстовые. Как можно ускорить выполнение запроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как можно ускорить выполнение запроса?

```
CREATE INDEX idx_telephone ON clients1 (telephone);
CREATE INDEX idx_telephone ON clients2 (telephone);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! При 40 000 записей время запроса уменьшилось с 6 мин до 5 сек =)